# bashrc or bash_profile?

Tags: scripts, startup, bash

I know the difference between the two bash login scripts:

`.bashrc` is run only by "non-login" shells.

`.bash_profile` (or `.bash_login` or `.profile`) is executed by "login" shells.

Does anyone have some good examples of what things that are a better fit for login-only execution, such that I'd only put them in `.bash_profile`, but they wouldn't really make sense in `.bashrc`?

(I know most of us source `.bashrc` out of `.bash_profile`, so there doesn't seem to be much point in the opposite question...)

Comment: See also [the same question at Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since a `.bashrc` is for non-login shells, I avoid any commands which echo to the screen. I've also run into experiences where echo statements in `.bashrc` will cause sftp and rsync commands to fail (and maybe scp commands as well).

```
# Print some information as we log in
# -s: OS Name -n: Node name -r: OS Release
uname -snr
uptime
```

Also, you generally won't run ssh-agent from a non-interactive shell. So I have this in `.bash_profile`.

```
if [ -f ~/.ssh/ssh-agent ]; then . ~/.ssh/ssh-agent; fi
```

Comment: If you use ~/.profile instead of ~/.bash_profile things will still work even if you change shells.. ~/.bash_profile is for bash specific things.

Comment: But bash will only run EITHER .bash_profile OR .profile, so if you're going to use both, you need to source .profile from within .bash_profile or something. That isn't a bad idea, actually...

Comment: @Source & @Don : Good points. I used to have Bashisms in my .bash_profile, but now I've switched to something more universal. Maybe using .profile is in order.

Comment: Regarding [output-producing commands in `.bashrc` interfering with remote file transfer methods implemented via standard streams](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976183/scp-033h-message), the solution is to put such commands *under* code that checks if the shell is interactive and continues only if it is. Users' default `.bashrc` files in Ubuntu, copied from `/etc/skel/.bashrc` upon account  creation, as well as the systemwide `/etc/bash.bashrc`, already contain code that checks and returns if the shell is noninteractive (though one must still put one's output-producing commands *under* them).

Answer (score 10):

Byobu is a great example of something you should never ever put in a `.bashrc`.

Otherwise, it will recursively run itself in every single one of its 'virtual terminals' ;-)

You can try it though, it's sort of fun.

That why you put it in `.profile`, so byobu (which really is a just wrapper around screen) is only loaded, once, at login-time. And byobu itself can start new interactive bash sessions.

Comment: That's a good example. Thanks for the pointer to Byobu as well. Now to go try it out.