# Hide current working directory in terminal

Tags: bash

As a default, the terminal prompt shows something like:

```
user@system:/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4$
```

the deeper you go into the filesystem, the less space is left for typing in commands. Can I change this to only show something like:

```
>
```

I mean, I can just type `pwd` to show where I am at. ;)

Comment: This should be a comment but I can't comment, sorry. In addition to hiding the current directory, the following PS1 value will visually seperate your bash commands nicely: `export PS1="\n___" `

Comment: experimented on Oli's solutions. The color fonts work well in the terminal: export PS1='\[\033[0;35m\]\h\[\033[0;33m\] \w\[\033[00m\]: '

Answer (score 193, accepted):

```
export PS1='\u@\h: '
```

That results in `oli@bert:` for my prompt.

If you really want something as minimalist as you ask for, try this:

```
export PS1='> '
```

You can attach that to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file to have it persist between logins.

You can also get creative with some colours. Here's what I use on my servers:

```
export PS1='\[\033[0;35m\]\h\[\033[0;33m\] \w\[\033[00m\]: '
```

Giving (it's easier to see on a full black background):

[image: My terminals]

[Glossary of acceptable characters in PS1](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)

Comment: You can also have newlines (\n) as part of the prompt, so you could put all the info and the '>' on separate lines.

Comment: what is the format used for setting up the colors?

Comment: @SyedRakibAlHasan Try `echo -e "\e[31mHello World\e[0m"` or `echo -e "\033[31mHello\e[0m World"` in a terminal, that should give you a clue. [source](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)

Answer (score 123):

Just to expand on Oli's answer (and so that I have a bookmark for those short-hand symbols):

The bash prompt (`stefano@linux:~$`) is only the first of a couple of prompts
you might see:

- **PS1**: the default prompt you see when you open a shell

  It's value is stored in an environment variable called `PS1`. To see its value,
  type

  `echo $PS1`

  This will give you something like

  ```
  \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
  ```

  To change it, you can set a new value for the variable:

  ```
  export PS1="\u > "
  ```

  This will result in a prompt like this:

  ```
  stefano >
  ```
- **PS2**: is your secondary prompt. This gets shown when a command is not finished.
  Type `echo "asd` and hit enter, the secondary prompt will let you enter more
  lines until you close the inverted commas.
- **PS3** is the prompt used for [`select`(2)](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/manpage?2+select)
- **PS4** is the prompt used for [image] [stack traces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) (default: `+`)

To make the changes permanent, you append them to the end of `.bash_profile` (or `.bashrc`, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1528/bashrc-or-bash-profile)) in your
home directory.

Here's a more or less complete list of shorthand that you can use when composing these:

- **`\a`**     The 'bell' character
- **`\A`**     24h Time
- **`\d`**     Date (e.g. Tue Dec 21)
- **`\e`**     The 'escape' character
- **`\h`**     Hostname (up to the first ".")
- **`\H`**     Hostname
- **`\j`**     No. of jobs currently running (ps)
- **`\l`**     Current tty
- **`\n`**     Line feed
- **`\t`**     Time (hh:mm:ss)
- **`\T`**     Time (hh:mm:ss, 12h format)
- **`\r`**     Carriage return
- **`\s`**     Shell (i.e. bash, zsh, ksh..)
- **`\u`**     Username
- **`\v`**     Bash version
- **`\V`**     Full Bash release string
- **`\w`**     Current working directory
- **`\W`**     Last part of the current working directory
- **`\!`**     Current index in history
- **`\#`**     Command index
- **`\$`**     A "#" if you're root, else "$"
- **`\\`**     Literal Backslash
- **`\@`**     Time (12h format with am/pm)

You can of course insert any literal string, and any command:

```
export PS1="\u \$(pwd) > "
```

Where `$(pwd)` stands in place of "the output of" pwd.

- If the command substitution is escaped, as in `\$(pwd)`, it's evaluated every time the prompt is displayed, otherwise, as in `$(pwd)`, it's only evaluated once when bash is started.

If you want your prompt to feature colours, you can use bash's colour codes to do it. The code consists of three parts:

```
40;33;01
```

- The first part before the semicolon represents the text style.

  - 00=none
  - 01=bold
  - 04=underscore
  - 05=blink
  - 07=reverse
  - 08=concealed
- The second and third part are the colour and the background color:

  - 30=black
  - 31=red
  - 32=green
  - 33=yellow
  - 34=blue
  - 35=magenta
  - 36=cyan
  - 37=white

Each part can be omitted, assuming starting on the left. i.e. "1" means bold, "1;31" means bold and red. And you would get your terminal to print in colour by escaping the instruction with `\33[` and ending it with an `m`. 33, or 1B in hexadecimal, is the ASCII sign "ESCAPE" (a special character in the ASCII character set). Example:

```
"\33[1;31mHello World\33[m"
```

Prints "Hello World" in bright red.

Comment: I appended `export PS1='\[\033[1;31m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \$> '` to `/etc/bash.bashrc` but nothing seemed to change... it works on a per session, but i cant seem to make it permanent.

Answer (score 9):

Another alternative is to shorten the working directory path when it gets too long: [trim the terminal command prompt working directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17723/trim-the-terminal-command-prompt-working-directory)

> Create a small python script which implements the desired trimming logic.
>
> Example: ~/short.pwd.py
>
> ```
> import os
> from commands import getoutput
> from socket import gethostname
> hostname = gethostname()
> username = os.environ['USER']
> pwd = os.getcwd()
> homedir = os.path.expanduser('~')
> pwd = pwd.replace(homedir, '~', 1)
> if len(pwd) > 30:
>     pwd = pwd[:10]+'...'+pwd[-20:] # first 10 chars+last 20 chars
> print '[%s@%s:%s] ' % (username, hostname, pwd)
> ```
>
> Now test it, from a terminal:
>
> ```
> export PROMPT_COMMAND='PS1="$(python ~/.short.pwd.py)"'
> ```
>
> If you are ok with the result just append the command into your ~/.bashrc

Comment: Exa...~/short.pwd.py   ,
export ... ~/.short.pwd.py   
I think both have to be the same. Either you put an extra command in both the places or you don't do that at all.
But this is an excellent answer..

Answer (score 9):

I often want to do this temporarily. Here's what I do:

```
$ export OLD_PS1=$PS1                    # save Long Prompt to OLD_PS1
$ export PS1="\u > "export PS1="\u $ "   # change to PS1 to Short Prompt
$ export PS1=$OLD_PS1                    # restore Long Prompt to PS1
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

**for macOS users:**

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

*at the end of the file add the following line and save it*

```
export PS1='\u:\w\$ '
```

*result at home directory:*

```
user: ~$
```

*here* 
u for user
w for current working directory 
$ is to prompt to display

you can try the following styles:

```
export PS1='$ '
```

*to just have $ as prompt, nothing else.* 
*just like:*

```
$
```

Comment: Should have been the right answer. Works with Ubuntu as well. Nice and up to the point. Wonder why so many people paste long tutorials whereas only a one liner is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that helped me was: export PS1='$ '

In order to have this each time you open the terminal, write the command at the end of the .bashrc which you can open by 'cd' followed by 'gedit .bashrc'.

Hope this helps. Worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu 20.10 I used the following steps on the default .bashrc file in my home directory

```
0. cd ~
1. cp .bashrc .bashrc.bkpa
2. nano .bashrc
3. ctrl+w -> PS1
4. Change the PS1 block of code to the one below (I *AM* playing safe here)

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\$ '
fi

5. save file, exit
6. source .bashrc
```

reopen terminal

Answer (score 0):

In bash 4 you can use `PROMT_DIRTRIM=1` in your `.bashrc` file to trim down your current working directory path shown on terminal.

Courtesy : [How do I shorten the current directory path shown on terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381113/how-do-i-shorten-the-current-directory-path-shown-on-terminal)

here is some example.

before :

```bsh
username@pc:~/repos/project1/src$
```

after:

```bsh
username@pc:~/.../src$
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Add context to the link by replacing "link" with the title of the question

Comment: how is it now daddy?

Answer (score 0):

**To shorten the current working directory path**

- Open bashrc file:
- vim ~/.bashrc

  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}[\033[01;32m]\u@\h[\033[00m]:[\033[01;34m]\w[\033[00m]$ ‘
- In the above line of the .bashrc file,  change the ‘w’ to an uppercase letter like below:

  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}[\033[01;32m]\u@\h[\033[00m]:[\033[01;34m]\W[\033[00m]$ ‘
- Save the file and open a new terminal window.

Comment: Not what the OP asked.