# How can I shorten my command line (bash) prompt?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, prompt, ps1

Currently it is:

```
michael@Castle2012-Ubuntu-laptop01:~/Dropnot/webs/rails_v3/linker/spec/controllers$
```

Outside of renaming my machine and directory structure...

How could I make it be something more like:

```
michael:controllers$
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/816068/how-to-shorten-your-command-line-promptbash-like-spatry-does-it

Answer (score 328, accepted):

#### To change it for the current terminal instance only

Just enter `PS1='\u:\W\$ '` and press enter.

---

#### To change it "permanently"

In your `~/.bashrc`, find the following section:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

Remove the `@\h`, and replace the `\w` with an uppercase `\W`, so that it becomes:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u:\W\$ '
fi
```

Save, exit, close terminal and start another to see the result.

---

#### Tons more options!

- See [here](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-2.html) for a more extensive howto, with many more options
- See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/17738/58612) for using up a tiny Python script to set the prompt so that the shortening only occurs when you are deep in a directory structure.

Comment: You can also have a lot of information... and then a carriage return at the end as in http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88780/10043

Comment: Is there a way to make this global? In other words, if I sudo to another user, have this setting carry over, but only for myself (i.e., not for the user when they normally use their account)?

Comment: In order to have a shared .bashrc that works on both Linux and OSX I've since switched to http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127800/10043

Comment: i.e. `HOST='\033[02;36m\]\h'
HOST=' '$HOST
parse_git_branch () { git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'; }
TIME='\033[01;31m\]\t \033[01;32m\]'
LOCATION=' \033[01;34m\]`pwd | sed "s#\(/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}/\).*\(/[^/]\{1,\}/[^/]\{1,\}\)/\{0,1\}#\1_\2#g"`'
BRANCH=' \033[00;33m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
PS1=$TIME$USER$HOST$LOCATION$BRANCH
PS2='\[\033[01;36m\]>'`

Comment: but see the answer for actual code to use.

Comment: How would you undo this? Let's say I run PS1='\u:\W\$ ' in the shell. What could I enter to restore the longer command prompt line?

Comment: [More info](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)

Comment: This didn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Worked for me perfectly on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You'd probably want to not use `\[` or `\]`. Using `\001` and `\002` seems to prevent breaking the prompt on longer lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839271/bash-ps1-line-wrap-issue-with-non-printing-characters-from-an-external-command/24840720#24840720

Comment: FYI, this bit `PS1='\u:\W\$ '` also worked for me on Mac OS.

Answer (score 167):

Run this code in the current terminal

```
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3
```

Now the bash prompt will show only the last 3 directory names.
You can choose 1 to show only current directory. More information is available [in the GNU documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-PROMPT_005fDIRTRIM).

The effect:

```
/var/lib/apt/lists# PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3
/.../lib/apt/lists#
```

If you want to make it permanently, add the following line to `~/.bashrc` in the beginning:

```
PROMPT_DIRTRIM=3
```

or another number greater than zero.

Comment: Just a sidenote: This requires Bash 4.

Comment: Nice... I added a bach_alias for this (with a function) `promptdir() { PROMPT_DIRTRIM=$1; }` just to make live easier...

Comment: Is there way to trim intermediate directory only i.e. keep the first directory and last directory ? e.g. /var/.../lists#

Answer (score 28):

This is my preferred prompt setting:

added in `~/.bashrc`

```
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
```

it looks like this:

```
[user@hostname dirname]$
```

(with a space after the `$` sign)

Comment: How about this `PS1='\[\033[01;34m\][\u @ \h \W]\[\033[00m\]\$ '`, but adding space between each word looks ugly tho...

Comment: very useful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Personally I prefer to see only current folder in the bash prompt. I can do this with the following command:

```
PS1='\W\$ '
```

If you want it to take effect after each start then add the above command into your ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is super old but since nobody suggested creating an alias I figured I'd post. Using [Bash Prompt Escape Sequences](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html) I made an alias `shorten`

In `~/.bash_aliases` here you will notice the $Blue var to set the prompt colour which you can omit or change based on preference I also clear the terminal when calling shorten.

```
alias c='clear'

alias shorten='PS1="$Blue$USER:\W$ "&& c'
```

To achieve the OP's desired prompt string:

```
alias shorten='PS1="$USER:\W$ "'
```

I have colours defined in `~/.bashrc`copy and pasted from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt. On a side note what's with ansi code colours? I'm confused just looking at it.

```
Blue='\e[0;34m'         # Blue
```

Comment: A step by step guide for this would be so useful as I have no idea how to get to .bash_aliases. Thanks

Comment: "." prefix indicates a hidden directory or file.  The tilde "~" is short form of $HOME variable. So,  "~/.bash_aliases" is just short form of "/home/$USER/.bash_aliases". To open ".bash_aliases" you can either open a terminal and type "gedit /home/$USER/.bash_aliases" or "gedit ~/.bash_aliases" or in your home directory type ctrl-h to show hidden files and open file directly. Hope that helps. You may want to do a Google search for useful aliases as well.

Answer (score 2):

I [wrote a function](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164844/script-to-hide-names-in-command-prompt/1164845#1164845) you can modify to suit your needs:

```
function termprompt() {
    PS1="${PS1//@\\h/}"     # Remove @host
    PS1="${PS1//\\w/\\W}"   # Change from full directory to last name
}
```

Place this function at or near the bottom of `~/.bashrc` after the `PS1` line has been fully computed.

You would type `termprompt` whenever you wanted to shorten your prompt or, have `termprompt` called from the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` for permanency.

The advantage of this technique over many other answers is `.bashrc` can setup `PS1` in four different ways (xterm+no-color, xterm+color, no-xterm+no-color, no-xterm+color). This answer supports all four current methods and probably future methods too.

Another advantage is this method has less complex control codes to traverse over in order to insert your changes.