# How to edit displayed bash name

Tags: command-line, bash, settings, bashrc

I've done some googling, and looking around this stack overflow, but this one seems to elude me.

How might I reduce/edit the displayed bash name on the terminal prompt?
I.E.

This:

> fresearch@fresearch-MM061:~/Desktop/blog$

To:

> |>$

I (sort of) know who I am, and (sometimes) know where I am. I have a small laptop screen, and would rather have the screen space. I have read through some of the bash man pages, but I decided not to start mucking about with vital settings files, and no idea what I was doing.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh look, the exact thing I was looking for!

http://askubuntu.com/a/145626/265730

Man, I spent like 20 minutes looking for this before hand. #programmerproblems

Comment: You can lengthen it but have a [return] at the end.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88780/10043

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called `bash prompt`

To get `|>$` simply run `PS1="|>$"` in your terminal, if this is what you want then you should edit your .bashrc to make it permanent.

Find section looked like this:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

And if you are not using colored prompt, then correct line after word `else` before `fi`:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

to this line

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}|>$'
```