# How can I make my shell prompt look like a cheeseburger?

Tags: command-line, fonts, unicode, prompt

I want my shell prompt to look like a cheeseburger!

It would be nice if it also displayed: username, hostname, and current directory.

Comment: What font can display these Unicodes?

Comment: @the_Seppi, [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) is one suitable font, which on Ubuntu is part of the `ttf-ancient-fonts` package.

Comment: For time, user, host, directory AND git branch (!) see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/127799/10043

Comment: The Unicode character you used is the one for [hamburger](http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%8D%94), not cheeseburger. We must petition the Unicode committee to include more fast food-related glyphs. Where are nuggets? Why is there no "with bacon" combining glyph? How on Earth can a Double Whopper and a Big Mac be conflated to the same code point, despite the enormous difference in significance? It's outrageous.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? I only see , which isn't any fun! ;-)

Comment: @SPRBRN, [unicode-table.com](http://unicode-table.com/) can search for character: http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%F0%9F%8D%94

Comment: It doesn't look anything like that in the font I have here though.

Comment: @SPRBRN Use the answer - install taht font package, then the browser will find the glyph too, just like the terminal.

Comment: The source code for  is 

Comment: I have to say the question looks much better now that I've installed `ttf-ancient-fonts`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I shorten my command line (bash) prompt?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145618/how-can-i-shorten-my-command-line-bash-prompt)

Answer (score 161):

great choice!

```
$ sudo apt-get install ttf-ancient-fonts
$ export PS1="\\u@\h \\w  "
```

enjoy.

Answer (score 43):

**Putting a cheeseburger on the prompt:**

1. Install a unicode font that contains this character:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ttf-ancient-fonts
   ```
2. Try the prompt:

   ```
   export PS1="\\u@\h \\w   "
   ```
3. Make permanent the change (if you don't do that, it will reset once terminal is closed):

   - Run `nano .bashrc`
   - Go to the 59th line approx. (You can view the current line number pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
   - Locate these lines:

     ```
     if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
         PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
     else
         PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
     fi
     ```
   - Replace `\$` character a the end of the lines beginning with `PS1=` by the cheeseburger:

     ```
     if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
         PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]  '
     else
         PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\  '
     fi
     ```

---

**Typing a cheeseburger everywhere (linux only):**

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
2. A underlined lowercase `u` will appear.
3. Type **<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>**
4. Press <kbd>Return</kbd>
5. A nice cheeseburger will appear.

Comment: It doesn't show for me 

Comment: All I get is square

Comment: @FindMeInTheWoods, did you install ttf-ancient-fonts?

Comment: Ctrl-shift-u does not appear to work in xterm or emacs.

Comment: Ctrl-shift-u is not linux only, it's GTK only (should work in Windows GIMP, for example, too). Won't work neither in xterm nor emacs nor any Qt-based application including the whole of KDE. Also, there's no need to press Return, just release Ctrl and Shift, and the char will be entered.

Comment: @Ruslan: Sorry, it may be as you're saying. However `xterm` shows a small box when I enter Ctrl+Shift+U and it allows me to put a unicode character, but only in the "printable" range.

Answer (score 25):

I couldn't help but take this probably a step too far. This version updates your prompt to display a different character based on time of day, to illustrate what you should be doing at that time.

```
declare -A pp
pp=(["09"]="" ["07"]="" ["08"]="" [10]="" [11]="" [12]="" [13]="" [14]="" [15]="" [16]="" [17]="" [18]="" [19]="" [20]="" [24]="")
u_pp() {
  c=${pp[`date +"%H"`]}
  if [[ $c == "" ]]; then
    c=${pp[24]}
  fi
  PS1='\u@\h:\w${c} '
};
u_pp
export PROMPT_COMMAND="u_pp;"
```

Probably there's a more concise way to do it; my bash isn't all that great.

To add the current time of day on the left side, replace the assignment of `PS1`:

```
PS1='[\@] \u@\h:\w${c} '
```

Comment: I know this is the most stupid question to be asked in the `askubuntu`, but I'm just wondering do you have an idea on get this working with `mac`, coz I'm getting `no matches found: [9]=  ` when I add this in to my (mac) ~/.bash_profile :)

Comment: Oh crap, that's a string-vs-integer bug that I found and fixed on my machine, but forgot to update text.

Basically, change single-digit keys like [9] and [7] to ["08"] etc. See updated answer. My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 18):

If you can't install the 'ancient fonts' maybe a sideways ASCII art cheeseburger would work?

```
export PS1="\\u@\h \\w (||]"
```

Of course, there could be different ways of typing this, possibly including lettuce, pickles, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following code to create a useful and colorful prompt with an ASCII art hamburger. Well... to be correct, this is a cheeseburger, red meat, with salad on white Italian bread! Special delight! ;-)

Login as the user, go to the home folder and open the bashrc file:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Add or replace the following line:

```
export PS1="\[\e[01;37m\][\[\e[0m\]\[\e[01;32m\]\u\[\e[0m\]\[\e[00;37m\]@\[\e[0m\]\[\e[01;34m\]\h\[\e[0m\]\[\e[00;37m\] \[\e[0m\]\[\e[00;37m\]\t\[\e[0m\]\[\e[01;37m\] \W \e[1;37m(\e[1;32m|\e[1;33m|\e[1;31m|\e[1;37m]\\$ \[\e[0m\]"
```

Result (no colors):

```
[john@server003 15:39:14 ~ (|||]$
```

- Create your own format using the [**bashrcgenerator**](http://bashrcgenerator.com/).
- List of [**color codes**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt)

Answer (score 3):

Green Cheeseburger:

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;32m\][\u@\h \W]\ \[\e[0m\] '
```

Red Cheesburger:

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;31m\][\u@\h \W]\ \[\e[0m\] '
```

Bicycle:

```
export PS1="\\u@\h \\w  "
```

or

```
export PS1="\\u@\h \\w  "
```

Love hearts:

```
export PS1="\\u@\h \\w      "
```

Show the time on the left and a watch on the right:

```
export PS1="[\@] \u@\h  "
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from pasting the emoji into the prompt definition directly, you can use the Unicode code point for cheeseburger with `printf` and command substitution within the prompt:

```
$ PS1='$(printf "\U0001f354") $ '
 $ echo "Hello,my cheesy prompt!"
Hello,my cheesy prompt!
 $
```