# current directory only shown on top of terminal, how do I show it inside?

Tags: command-line

I don't know what I did, but somehow I made it so that when I change directories it shows up on the very top of the Terminal. Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about:

[image]

I am happy it's still working, probably a setting issue somehow. How do you change it so that when you change directories the information is found inside the terminal, not on top?

Comment: Please explain "I cannot show you a picture of what I am talking about because it won't show." Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean but... what's the output of `echo $PS1` ?

Comment: @Zanna-the output for $PS1 is \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]$\H\$.

Comment: @wjandrea-I thought that after I put my mouse over the image it would change but this time I was incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want the current working directory to show in your prompt.

According to your screenshot, your prompt is showing only your machine name. The output you gave for `echo $PS1` doesn't even give me that... I can't replicate your prompt without a bit of tinkering: maybe you have: `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\H\$` or... you're using a different shell maybe??

Here is the code for a really simple prompt that shows the username, computer name, and current working directory (enter this in a terminal to test):

```
PS1="\u@\h:\w$ "
```

But probably you want the working directory in your prompt AND in the window title... the normal prompt in Ubuntu is this:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

which is set in `~/.bashrc` by:

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

So maybe you put something in your `.bashrc` to override that. Have a look at the end of it for lines like

```
export PS1="some code here"
```

or

```
PS1="some code here"
export PS1
```

To see if it has been overridden, and comment out those lines if they are there (put `#` at the start of the line) or just remove them.

You can also check that the section I pasted above (line 38-73 in my `.bashrc`) exists and hasn't been changed, if you just want to restore the normal prompt.

To get a completely clean `.bashrc`

```
mv ~/.bashrc{,.bak} && cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

If you want to customise your prompt, you can keep playing around until you get what you want... [this site](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/) is helpful for reference.

When you have what you want add to .bashrc

```
export PS1="your code here "
```

Also see [one of my favourite AU questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625021/how-can-i-make-my-shell-prompt-look-like-a-cheeseburger)

Comment: The default `.bashrc` has three sections about the PS1: (1) Color prompt (not relevant in this case). (2) The normal prompt: `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '`. (3) The window title: `PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"`. The third part is the reason that there are square brackets in his PS1.

Comment: yes... but what happened to their prompt? Maybe I should ask for more clarification before answering... thanks for commenting... I will edit

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea. I'm just trying to explain the part inside square brackets.

Comment: sorry I forgot to @ you @wjandrea but you came back anyway... I edited *shrug* but too many assumptions maybe

Comment: I'd like to place a bet that this is due to copying dotfiles from the Interwebs.

Comment: sounds likely @0x23212f :)