# How to change the font style of terminal prompt in Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: command-line, fonts, mate, ubuntu-mate, prompt

The Mate terminal like any other terminal emulator in Ubuntu or any other OS has an input line like:

```
abc@xyz:~$
```

How to change the font style of this particular line?
Other than this one inputs commands to the line above and then the command generates messages thereafter. I want to set this text to a different style. I can do that using by going to `Edit>Profile preferences`. But this changes the Font style of the input line to the same one. I want there to be a difference between the input line text and rest of the text in the terminal so that after a command has printed messages verbosely, I can trace-back the input line without hard-gazing.

Ubuntu 16.04 seems to come with a default color for the input line that remains unchanged by tweaking options in `Profile preferences`.

Comment: It is not possible to have different font size for the prompt than for the rest of the terminal's contents. You could instead use colors, bold and/or italic text etc. for your prompt.

Comment: @egmont I think that is what the OP wants - to change the style, as you mention, not the actual font

Comment: @Zanna My bad, I guess I misread "font style" as "font size".

Comment: not bad at all @egmont I think your comment was helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>(Some of the screenshots below reveal use of a particular text editor. If this is problematic for the reader, they are hereby begged to consider the use of this editor by the post author an act of blameless naivety)</sub>

The terminal prompt is a part of your user environment called `PS1`. It is defined in your `.bashrc` file, which you can edit to change it. You can see what it is currently with `echo $PS1`. Here is mine:

```
$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;35m\]\w\$\[\033[00m\]
```

This makes my prompt look like this compared to some command...

[image]

**Making a coloured prompt** is achieved by uncommenting this line in your `.bashrc`

```
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

so it looks like this:

```
force_color_prompt=yes
```

This causes the prompt to be set by the line after `if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then`

which by default is:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

The colours are set by these codes:

- light green `\[\033[01;32m\]`
- white `\[\033[00m\]`
- light blue `\[\033[01;34m\]`

and then back to white. You can see they are the same apart from the number in the second set of brackets. Here's a few more escape codes to choose from:

```
Blue        0;34     Light Blue    1;34
Green       0;32     Light Green   1;32
Cyan        0;36     Light Cyan    1;36
Red         0;31     Light Red     1;31
```

Here are some other options to make your prompt stand out

---**All tested in MATE terminal on Ubuntu MATE 16.04**---

When applying these changes to a white prompt, I leave this line commented:

```
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

And edit the fourth line of this section of .bashrc:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

If you want to apply underline, and highlight effects to a **coloured prompt**, then as explained before you need to uncomment `force_color_prompt=yes`, and edit the **second** line instead of the fourth. In the examples below, I am referring to the "fourth line" and "second line" from the snippet above.

**Bold prompt:**

Change the fourth line to include the escape sequences `\[\e[1m\]` (bold) and `\[\e[0m\]` (stop bold)

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[1m\]\u@\h:\w\$ \[\e[0m\]'
```

[image]

Not a big difference - I include the line above for comparison.

In the colour escape sequences "light" colours (with `1` instead of `0` as shown in table above) are considered bold. I tried using the bold sequence on the coloured prompt, but it seems MATE terminal doesn't allow this to make it *even more bold*. I also tried it using `setaf` code but still no result. Maybe I'm getting something wrong. I also couldn't manage an italic prompt, and I didn't even try a blinking prompt - that's just not OK.

**Underlined prompt:**

Change the fourth line to include the escape sequences `\[\e[4m\]` and `\[\e[24m\]`

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[4m\]\u@\h:\w\$ \[\e[24m\]'
```

[image]

For underlined coloured prompt, uncomment `force_color_prompt=yes` and add the `\[\e[4m\]` sequence to the second line twice. The existing reset codes will terminate the effect:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[4m\]\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\e[4m\]\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

[image]

**Highlighted prompt:**

Change the fourth line to include `\[\e[7m\]` and `\[\e[27m\]`

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[7m\]\u@\h:\w\$ \[\e[27m\]'
```

[image]

For colour highlighting, uncomment the `#force_color_prompt=yes` and change the colour escape codes in the second line to have a `4` instead of a `3`, for example:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;42m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;44m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

[image]

To get the highlighting all one colour, remove the first reset and the second colour sequence:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;42m\]\u@\h:\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

[image]

For more exotic options, see [my favourite AU question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625021/how-can-i-make-my-shell-prompt-look-like-a-cheeseburger) and [this site](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/index.html) for a detailed guide.

Obviously I recommend making backups as you play around , but if you ever FUBAR your `.bashrc` you can just copy a fresh one from `/etc/skel`:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: And if one wants to make the prompt font bold?

Comment: Easy :) I'll update my answer later when I have time to get screenshots uploaded @user_1_1_1 :)

Comment: @user_1_1_1 here's some more options for you

Comment: @Zanna, how can I make font size of commands bigger than rest terminal output?

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh I am not aware of any way to do this. I believe the font size is a setting of the terminal emulator, or for virtual terminals of the kernel, and cannot be changed in the prompt code. You may want to ask a new question about this, to see if anyone knows better and help others find the information in future

Comment: @Zanna, I got it's solution at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064344/how-to-convert-script-command-output-into-plain-text/1064355#1064355