# Changing text color in-line?

Tags: command-line, bash, echo, gnome-color-manager

Short question:

Using bash, is it possible to print a sentence such that each individual word has a different color?

I.e; print a word in-line, change the text color, repeat?

Comment: Do you mean customize colors at terminal? What is your ubuntu release? [This can be useful to you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815076/how-to-change-the-font-style-of-terminal-prompt-in-ubuntu-mate-16-04)

Comment: @Redbob I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04. And no. I want to print a sentence from a bash program that has a custom coloring without interfering with the rest of the text/profile.

Comment: How  [about this](https://linuxtidbits.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/output-color-on-bash-scripts/)?

Comment: @Redbob Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Tks! I encourage you to develop this solution and post results as your answer. It will be useful and "maybe" more practical then the solution we indicated.

Comment: Probably duplicate and already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux

Comment: If you are going to use colors often, define them in .bashrc or I call .envrc as I use the same variables with zsh - http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/envrc . If you are wanting a portable script, often easiest to define colors at the top of the script .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ANSI escape sequences

You can use ANSI escape sequences. It should work in text screens as well as most linux terminal window emulators.

See this link for details,

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Example 1: White text on black background

```
echo -e "\0033[37;40m###############\0033[0m"
```

Example 2: Black text on greyish white background

```
echo -e "\0033[30;47m###############\0033[0m"
```

Example 3: Using the variables `inversvid`, `greenback`, `blueback` and `resetvid`

```
inversvid="\0033[7m"
resetvid="\0033[0m"
greenback="\0033[1;37;42m"
blueback="\0033[1;37;44m"
echo -e "$inversvid Now it is inverse colours $resetvid"
echo -e "$greenback Now it is greenback $resetvid and $blueback now blueback $resetvid"
```

[image]

### Declare and store variables

Example of basic ANSI colour variables, that I use in bash shellscripts, and that you might find useful,

```
inversvid="\0033[7m"
resetvid="\0033[0m"
redback="\0033[1;37;41m"
greenback="\0033[1;37;42m"
blueback="\0033[1;37;44m"
```

Example of advanced ANSI colour variable (that almost matches the mkusb logo colour),

```
logoansi="\0033[38;5;0;48;5;148m"
```

The advanced ANSI colours work in most terminal window emulators, but not in text screens, where the colour defaults to 'the nearest basic colour'.

---

- It is straightforward to declare and store the variables in a bash shellscript (near the beginning, at least before they are used).
- If you want to use them interactively, you can declare and store the variables in the configuration file `~/.bashrc`

And of course, you can create [modified] variables to perform what you want.