# output ascii art in a red color on terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, banner, ascii-art

so i wanted to make a MR ROBOT default banner, but i don't know how to make the output in a red Color in terminal, could somebody please help? 
also does anybody have the Original MR ROBOT ascii art? if so please drop it here.

ps: using kali linux 2018.1 release

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/958435/changing-text-color-in-line/958460

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `tput` is very handy for mobile environments, ASCII colouring is always an alternative:

```sh
echo -e "\x1B[31m MR ROBOT \x1B[0m"
```

will output the term `MR ROBOT` in red font.

```
\x1B[31m = RED
\x1B[32m = GREEN
\x1B[96m = Blue
\x1B[01;95m = PURPLE
\x1B[01;94m = VIOLET
\x1B[01;93m = Yellow
\x1B[01;91m = ORANGE
\x1B[01;90m = GREY
\x1B[01;89m = WHITE
\x1B[0m = Back to your terminal's default colour
```

Related: [How to change the output color of echo in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux) on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
$ tput setaf 1; echo 'MR ROBOT'; tput sgr0
```

[image]

And as explained in comments, do not hard-code ANSI color escape sequences in your program! The `tput` command lets you interact with the terminal database in a sane way: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037

Comment: thank you. but instead of 'MR RROBOT' i have a custom big ascii artwork, you see i want to make it as a banner for my terminal. a default one if that's a correct word, i'm sorry i'm new to all of this

Comment: you can replace the `echo` part with another command or `cat  file`