# "export PS1=" for customizing shell prompt

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, prompt, ps1

I wanted to customize my shell prompt to include the time. So, I did `export PS1='\t\w\$'`.

My prompt now looks like `18:57:37~$`. I don't know how to prepend it with `username@hostname`.

Also, I don't know how to change the color of the each parameter for `\t`, `\w`, and so on.

After all the testing how do I set it back to the default?

Finally, where does the export line go? I looked in the `~/.profile`, but there isn't the line `export PS1='\t\w\$'`.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/625021/how-can-i-make-my-shell-prompt-look-like-a-cheeseburger and nearly everything in https://askubuntu.com/search?q=change+prompt and https://askubuntu.com/search?q=prompt+color

Comment: Wouldn't that solve all your problems? bashrcgenerator.com/

Comment: okay, at least would you tell me how to back to the default?? I think there are all the information in the manual, but I'm asking things because of the lack of summarizing for my specific task. I don't expect all answer is perfect for my question, but any answer helps me to trigger further research. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`PS1` is set in your `~/.bashrc`. This file contains settings which will be applied in every interactive shell. An interactive Bash shell is what you get when you open a terminal in Ubuntu, unless you have set a different default shell for your user.

In an interactive shell, we need a prompt, and it's nice if the prompt gives us some useful info, like the current working directory, the current user and the hostname, as the Ubuntu `PS1` does.

Here are the lines which set `PS1` in the default version of `.bashrc` for my system, `/etc/skel/.bashrc`

```bsh
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

From `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '` you can see that the escape codes for `username` and `hostname` are `\u` and `\h` respectively

```
zanna@toaster:~$ PS1="\u@\h"
zanna@toaster
```

If you want to add the time and current working directory:

```
zanna@toasterPS1="\u@\h \t \w "
zanna@toaster 10:43:32 ~
```

To get colours, you need to use the colour escape sequences. You can see some in the color_prompt assignment in `.bashrc`

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

For example, `\033[01;34m` is blue:

[image: PS1 assignment]

Oops! Now the text after is blue as well... better change it back to white:

[image: PS1 with color reassignment]

We should surround colour assignments with escaped square brackets, otherwise Bash will think they are printing characters of the prompt and use them to calculate its size. This gives weird effects when you try to interact with your history, so here's the corrected version:

```
PS1="\[\033[01;34m\]\u@\h \t \w \[\033[00m\]"
```

When you have finished playing, you can return the prompt to default by [closing the terminal and opening a new one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302548/hash-symbols-turned-into-pound-symbols-%c2%a3-after-catting-a-binary/302549#302549) ;) or by running

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

[image: my PS1 back to normal]

I set my `PS1` like this using the code already in `.bashrc`, uncommenting `#force_color_prompt=yes` and changing the colour codes. Here you can see the lines I have changed to set it:

```bsh
$ diff .bashrc /etc/skel/.bashrc 
46c46
< force_color_prompt=yes
---
> #force_color_prompt=yes
60c60
<     PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;35m\]\w\$\[\033[00m\] '
---
>     PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

(there are more lines changed after this, but they aren't relevant)

You could do the same, but add a `\t` into the `color_prompt` line somewhere, for example

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h \[\033[01;36m\]\t \[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;35m\]\w\$\[\033[00m\] '
```

For a list of ANSI escape codes for colours and more stuff, see [this guide to customising the prompt](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html).

---

I neglected to answer the last part of your question.

> Finally, where does the export line go? I looked in the `~/.profile`, but there isn't the line export `PS1='\t\w\$'`

I'm not sure whether you expected running `export VAR=val` would cause your `~/.profile` to be automatically modified. The `export` command never does this. Exporting a variable will only pass it into the environment of commands run from the current shell. When you exit the shell (and all of its child processes have exited), anything you exported from the shell is gone.

If you want to set an environment variable permanently, you generally need to add it to `~/.profile` explicitly. Some scripts you might use to install software may modify your `~/.profile` or other shell configuration files.

But `PS1` does not need to be exported into the environment. At the start of my answer I said that in an interactive shell we need a prompt, and I meant that *only* interactive shells need prompts (because the prompt helps the user interact with the shell). No other command needs `PS1`.

You might be thinking that it could be useful for `PS1` to be passed to any child shells of the current shell. When you start an interactive shell within a shell by running `bash`, the new shell will not inherit the shell variables of the calling shell; only its environment variables. So, to pass variables to a child shell, we should `export` them.

But exporting `PS1` will usually* fail to pass its value to a child shell, because it is reset by the shell's configuration files, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`. So, closing the terminal (as I suggested earlier) is not necessary; even running `bash` will return your prompt to its usual form:

```
zanna@toaster:~$ export PS1='\t -> '
22:43:54 -> bash
zanna@toaster:~$
```

(if you `exit` this shell, the edited prompt comes back)

* I say usually, because, although non-interactive shells *always* unset `PS1`, an interactive Bash shell will preserve the value of `PS1` if it is set. This isn't obvious, because as shown in the preceding example it typically gets reset by the configuration files. We can uncover it by changing `PS1` and then starting a new shell that doesn't read our config files:

```
zanna@toaster:~$ export PS1='\t -> '
22:55:04 -> bash --norc
22:55:09 ->
```

So, to conclude, there is no `export` line for `PS1` in `~/.profile` because `PS1` is not an environment variable and has no business being one, since only interactive shells need it, and for the reason that interactive shells need `PS1`, it is set in `~/.bashrc`, because unless told not to, all interactive Bash shells `source` `~/.bashrc`, so `~/.bashrc` doesn't need to `export` `PS1` to be inherited by child shells (but if you do really want to `export` some value of `PS1` other than the one in your `.bashrc` to a child shell, you can do so by preventing that shell from sourcing `.bashrc`).

---

*I have been able to extend my answer thanks to Eliah Kagan, who explained how Bash treats PS1 [here in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41604268#41604268) and in more detail in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960551/why-arent-variables-like-ps1-in-printenv/961781#961781).*

Comment: This is amazing. I feel like I own Ubuntu. Thanks :)

Comment: 1;36, Light Cyan is very cool stuff.

Comment: Yes, I expected running "export VAR=val" would cause my ~/.profile to be automatically modified. I only understand your answer partially, but it is very helpful. Thanks :)