# How to customize the LXTerminal console in Lubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, customization, console, lxterminal

first say hello, I'm new to the site.
I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS on my computer and I still have to familiarize myself with the OS.
One of the things I can not change is the appearance of LXTerminal, which comes from black background and white letters.
I just wanted to change, for example, the color of the place where I am.
Example: user @ user: ~ / Documents $
As I say, everything is blank. Only the directories that are blue change.
I have seen several articles, but in none I find the editing tools that this console has.
It shows me: Edit> Preferences> And there are only four tabs to choose from:
Style, Show, Advanced, Shortcuts
I can not find a way to give it a little appearance, I have seen that with commands it is also possible, but with what I saw so far I am not capable.
If you can give me some idea or where to look for information.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Your prompt is $PS1; you change it to control the text that makes you prompt (and the colors used).  Refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/984060/export-ps1-for-customizing-shell-prompt.  *Note if you change $PS1, it effects new terminals and not your current one (unless...)*  Try `echo $PS1` to view your current prompt value

Comment: Hice eco en $ PS1 y el resultado fue: `\ [\ e] 0; \ u @ \ h: \ w \ a \] $ {debian_choroot: + ($ debian_chroot)} \ u @ \ h: \ w \ $ `No sé exactamente QUÉ y CÓMO modificar para poder cambiar los colores . Volveré a revisar la documentación que se encuentra en las preguntas y enlaces que me propuso. Gracias  @guiverc por el apoyo. Si lo consigo, comento y puedo responder.

Comment: Have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt which I think is more helpful.  *Even if you didn't understand all of the post I provided in my first comment, I hoped it'd provide clues helpful for your search in how.*

Comment: Thanks, I've been lost all day without getting anything. Edit the file as it comes in the documentation to change the user name and directory to green and the commands to target, without success, everything goes blank:
if ["$ color_prompt" = yes]; then
PS1 = '[$ FGRN $ {debian_chroot: + ($ debian_chroot)} \ u $ FGRN: $ FGRN \ w $ FGRN] \\ $ RS'
else
PS1 = '$ {debian_chroot: + ($ debian_chroot)} \ u @ \ h: \ w \ $'

Comment: 'code' is difficult to read in comments; if you need to paste things like that put it in your question, ideally with a short note as to why & separation if needed.  Questions & Answers can be edited & allow far greater formatting.  $FGRN needs declaration; did you define it?  (the FGRN="\[\033[32m\]" step; *I didn't try and read your shell sorry*).  If you're still having troubles, search for other howto's  (eg. https://www.howtogeek.com/307701/how-to-customize-and-colorize-your-bash-prompt/)  as it's a `bash` issue, and the same in almost any *nix

Answer (score 0):

If you want colours you have 2 easy options.

1. Upgrade to 18.04,
   the new terminal has a funky colour scheme.

[image: ubuntu 18.04 colour scheme]

2. Go to software and download terminal.

System tools-> Software, then search terminal.
The store typically has pictures from which you can get a feel for its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

First backup using `cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc-backup`

Edit the file `~/.bashrc` and replace these lines:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Save the file and reopen the terminal to see if you like it.

If you don't like it restore the backup with: `cp ~/.bashrc-backup ~/.bashrc` and reopen the terminal.

### What it looks like

[image: bashrc2.png]

#### NOTES:

- You don't need 18.04. This works in Ubuntu 16.04 and Lubuntu 16.04 (but the background there is black and the fonts are as well defined)

Comment: Thank you @WinEunuuchs2Unix, this is what I did but I have not replaced correctly since everything is still blank. What should I put so that the user and directory where I am are green and the ones I write blank?
Sorry for the delay in responding.

Comment: @MariCruzFernandez The contents of your `~/Documents`, `~/Music` and `~/Pictures` directories will all be blank until you save some new work into them. Try `ll /etc` if you want to see a directory with files.