# How put the appearance of Linux Lite in from ubuntu terminal?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal, xfce4-terminal

I want to make the Terminal of Ubuntu look like Linux Lite?

Because in Linux Lite I can see the branch in git and it looks cool.

[image]

Comment: Linux Lite uses the Mate desktop terminal emulator. So, `mate-terminal` is probably what you want.

Comment: @ChanganAuto No, mate-terminal does not look like this either.

Comment: This link is from a deleted answer which was deleted for being a link-only answer. https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell Someone may be able to write a nice answer with detailed instructions.

Comment: All I see from your provided picture is a modified $PS1 (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt) but I maybe missing what you want us to notice. Also helpful maybe https://askubuntu.com/questions/984060/export-ps1-for-customizing-shell-prompt but your tagging gnome-terminal, xfce-terminal confuses me?  Prompt or $PS1 works on many terminals.

Comment: Just to clarify that what this question was asking for is currently available through starship and zoxide packages. The following post and included video provide a quick an easy way to setup everything as seen/requested by @Aguila95: https://christitus.com/beautiful-bash/