# How to change colours in bash prompt

Tags: command-line, bash, configuration, bashrc

I have followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145618/how-can-i-shorten-my-command-line-bash-prompt) and in the [howto link](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-2.html) that is provided there. However nowhere does it appear to say how I can change the colours of the different parts, because currently I set it to:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}[\t] \u@\h:\w\$ '
```

But the text is still all white, how could I perhaps make the numbers for the time green, and my username and computer name light blue? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04.

Comment: Bash prompt colors: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html. I use `PS1="\[\033[33m\]\@ \w \$ \[\033[0m\]"`.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt

Comment: Suggestion: have a look at [liquidprompt](https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, open up your ~/.bashrc file and enable color prompts:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

uncomment the line `#force_color_prompt=yes`

Then, change the PS1 line directly **under** the line `if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then`

to:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[00;32m\][\t] \[\033[01;34m\]\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

As you can see, 01:34m is light blue and 00:32m is green. Light green would be 01:32m instead of 00:32m.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to save the file. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

Then, run the following command to apply the changes by "sourcing" your bashrc file:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

The changes should now apply to every newly opened terminal under your user.

[click here for more info](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt)

Comment: What code gets you the colour white?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda `\[\033[01;37m\]` for bright white and `\[\033[00;37m\]` for white

Comment: @ParanoidPanda here's a list https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#List_of_colors_for_prompt_and_Bash

Answer (score 11):

Here is one that a friend of mine and I have been working on.  It gives a gray dashed line when you are a normal user, then if you are running commands as a root user, it changes to red for both the dashed line and the text.

[image]

In your `.bashrc` file, add the following code to the bottom of the file:

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.bash_ps1" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bash_ps1"
fi
```

**EDIT:** Also, add it to the bottom of the `/root/.bashrc` as well.  This is for if you switch to the `root` user by issuing the command `sudo su -`. **(The rest of the edit is continued below code)**

Then copy and paste the rest of this code to a new file called `/home/<username>/.bash_ps1`

```
# Fill with minuses
# (this is recalculated every time the prompt is shown in function prompt_command):
fill="--- "

reset_style='\[\033[00m\]'

# determine if root or not
a=$(id|awk -F\( '{print $1}')
if [ "$a" = "uid=0" ]
then
    # for root
    status_style=$reset_style'\[\033[1;31m\]' # bold red; use 0;37m for lighter color
    command_style=$reset_style'\[\033[1;31m\]' # bold red
else
    # for other users
    status_style=$reset_style'\[\033[0;90m\]' # gray color; use 0;37m for lighter color
    command_style=$reset_style'\[\033[1;29m\]' # bold black
fi
prompt_style=$reset_style

# Prompt variable:

PS1="$status_style"'$fill $(date +"%m/%d/%y ")\t\n'"$prompt_style"'${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$'"$command_style "

# Reset color for command output
# (this one is invoked every time before a command is executed):
trap 'echo -ne "\033[00m"' DEBUG

function prompt_command {
# create a $fill of all screen width minus the time string and a space:
let fillsize=${COLUMNS}-18
fill=""
while [ "$fillsize" -gt "0" ]
do
    fill="-${fill}" # fill with underscores to work on
    let fillsize=${fillsize}-1
done

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|rxvt*)
    bname=$(basename "${PWD/$HOME/~}")
    echo -ne "\033]0;${bname}: ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD/$HOME/~}\007"
    ;;
    *)
    ;;
esac
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

**EDIT (Part 2):** Now create a link to the `.bash_ps1` in your `/root` folder

```
sudo -s
cd /root
ln -s /home/<username>/.bash_ps1
```

You can change any of the above code to fit your needs.  This is one that I use actually at work so that I know if I am typing in commands as a `root` user that could be potentially dangerous.  Plus, the time stamp appears just above each line you type, making it a little easier if you scroll back to see when you typed in that command.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Seems to work =)

Comment: I like this one, nice!

Comment: This didn't work for me; text is white with normal privilegies(as it should be) but normal color(light white) when I'm root

Comment: @Wildcard Sorry, I missed that part of if you type in `sudo su -` to switch to the root user.  I normally don't do a full switch to root, so I missed that part.  But I did make edits so it does work for it now.