# prompt only appears correctly after I use "bash" command

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I edited my .bashrc file to change the command prompt. I got it to work but the problem is it doesn't launch immediately upon opening the terminal. But when I type "bash" it appears correctly. Is there any way to get the prompt to appear correctly without using the bash command?

Comment: Did you create .bashrc file in the ~/ directory? Example at: [Custom Terminal Prompt](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145618/how-can-i-shorten-my-command-line-bash-prompt)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, i just entered the following code into ~/.bash_profile:

```
if [[ $- == *i* && -f ~/.bashrc ]]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```