# Toggle format of gnome terminal prompt string by command?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

My terminal has a default prompt format like this one:

> username@boxname /path/to/current/directory $

The code that produces it looks like this: (it has some color definitions too)

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\]'
```

If the path to the current directory gets too long it becomes unpleasant to work with the terminal because you constantly break lines. In such cases I would prefer a format that produces a shorter string like this one:

> username@boxname current_dir_name $

The code that produces it would look like this (again with color):

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] $(basename ${PWD}) \$ \[\033[00m\]'
```

Does anyone know how I could easily toggle the format of the current terminal window from one style to the other by just typing for example: `prompttoggle`?

Comment: Are you aware of bash's [PROMPT_DIRTRIM](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145618/how-can-i-shorten-my-command-line-bash-prompt/459355#459355) parameter?

Comment: @steeldriver not until now. Toggling between `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=0` and `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=1` seems simpler than toggling between different values for `PS1` and the result is almost the same. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Using `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` one could also add arguments to the command. If you pass no argument you toggle between `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=0` and `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=1` and if you pass a number as an argument you set `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` to it. `promptlen` would be a more appropriate name for the command then.

Answer (score 10):

Store both your long and short `PS1` variables under a different name:

```
PS1short='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\]'
PS1long='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] $(basename ${PWD}) \$ \[\033[00m\]'
```

Make sure to set `PS1`to one of them initially:

```
PS1="$PS1long"
```

Then you can make an alias like this to toggle between the two PS1 values:

```
alias prompttoggle='if test "$PS1" = "$PS1long" ; then PS1="$PS1short" ; else PS1="$PS1long" ; fi'
```

---

Adding all four lines to your `~/.bashrc` file will ake the command available in your Bash sessions, here are they again for easier copying:

```
PS1short='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\]'
PS1long='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] $(basename ${PWD}) \$ \[\033[00m\]'
PS1="$PS1long"
alias prompttoggle='if test "$PS1" = "$PS1long" ; then PS1="$PS1short" ; else PS1="$PS1long" ; fi'
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a tiny `bash` function:

```
prompttoggle () { 
    if [[ $PS1 = *basename* ]]; then 
        export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\]'
    else 
        export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] $(basename ${PWD}) \$ \[\033[00m\]'
    fi ;}
```

The function above matches if the current `$PS1` contains `basename`, if yes, then the `PS1` without `basename` is set otherwise the one with `basename` is set.

Put the function in your `~/.bashrc` to get it available in all interactive sessions.

**Example:**

```
foo@bar:~/spam/egg$ prompttoggle () { 
>     if [[ $PS1 = *basename* ]]; then 
>         export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\]'
>     else 
>         export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] $(basename ${PWD}) \$ \[\033[00m\]'
>     fi ;}

foo@bar:~/spam/egg$ prompttoggle 

foo@bar egg $ prompttoggle

foo@bar ~/spam/egg $
```

Answer (score 5):

Or... make two *very* tiny functions and add to the end of your `~/.bashrc`

```
# short prompt
promptshort() { export PS1=$(echo "$PS1" | sed 's/\\w/\\W/g') ; }

# full length prompt
promptlong() { export PS1=$(echo "$PS1" | sed 's/\\W/\\w/g') ; }
```

for a shortened prompt, type `promptshort`, to go back to the full path, type `promptlong`

`\W` shows the current working directory only so `$(basename ${PWD})` is overkill imho

[image]

You could combine into one function but "long" and "short" are descriptive and both have less keystrokes than "toggle" ;)

Instead of adding a line to override PS1 I prefer to tweak the code that sets it (for example, uncomment `force_color_prompt=yes` and edit the line after `[ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then`)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `~/.bashrc` function definition that I personally use to reset/toggle my prompt from regular prompt to just `$`. Adapt it as necessary to suit your needs.

```
resetps() {
    if [ "$PS1" = "$ " ] 
    then
        PS1=$OLDPS1 
    else
        OLDPS1=$PS1 
        export OLDPS1 
        PS1="$ " 
    fi 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to your problem (long directories break the command line) and not specifically to your question (how to change the command prompt on the fly.)

I solved this problem years ago with this prompt:

```
PS1='\[\e[32;1m\]$? \u@\h \[\e[35;1m\]\w\[\e[m\]\n\$ '
#    └──green───┘         └──purple──┘  └─norm─┘
```

What this does:

1. output the exit value of the previous command **(this is incredibly useful)**
2. output the current user and host in one color
3. output the working directory in another color (adjust the colors to your taste)
4. **output the dollar and space on a new line**, ending the color sequences before the line break

This gives you all the space you need for your command, does not shift it right when you are in a deep directory structure, does not mangle the typing line with color codes (avoiding strange bugs that happen sometimes), while still giving you the colored hint on where the output of one command ended and the next one begun:

[image]