# I want to change the command prompt

Tags: hostname

I edited hostname in /etc/hostname and in /etc/hosts; I want the command prompt to be 'new' instead  of 'old'; now, what I have is old@new; is there any way to completely get rid of old? Hostname displays correctly as 'new'

Comment: You will have to change your username, please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/34074/how-do-i-change-my-username

Comment: You can get rid of the username "old" by editing the .bashrc file.  Remove the \u@ on the lines starting with PS1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I shorten my command line (bash) prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145618/how-can-i-shorten-my-command-line-bash-prompt)

Comment: If you want to change the command prompt, see here. If you want to change your host name, stay tuned, but in that case, please change your title to reflect the real question.