# How to keep the Linux prompt unchanged on changing directory?

Tags: command-line, bashrc

I don't want my prompt to grow as I change directory. It becomes pretty lengthy on ubuntu terminal and goes into multiple lines. Is there a way I change customize the PS1.

Comment: If the length of the prompt is your only concern, then please see [How can I shorten my command line (bash) prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145618/how-can-i-shorten-my-command-line-bash-prompt/459355#459355)

Comment: this might also help

https://www.linuxnix.com/linuxunix-shell-ps1-prompt-explained-in-detail/