# Adding a tab and newline to my terminal prompt

Tags: command-line, prompt

My terminal prompt is way too long. If I enter a long command, it gets wrapped to the next line which is hard to read.

I thought I'd take a page from ParrotOS and just have the commands entered on the line underneath the prompt.

---

Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145618/how-can-i-shorten-my-command-line-bash-prompt), I managed to get a newline added by going into `~/.bashrc` and changing

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

to (note the `\n` at the end):

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
```

This works. The `$` is on a newline now. The problem is, I'd also like to have it tabbed over a bit. I tried:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n\t\$ '
```

But that prints out a time:

```
myName@myMachine:~/someDir
14:59:15$
```

Apparently `\t` is a timestamp placeholder in this context?

How can I just get a literal tab in there to be printed? I could of course just add spaces, but that isn't very clean.

Comment: According to [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) there is no code for a horizontal tab. However, you can insert an arbitrary character into your prompt string. There is a [Tab character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key) for a horizontal tab, and its ASCII decimal code is 9. So you might be able to perform a horizontal tab in the prompt by inserting \011 (the octal value of decimal 9) into your sequence. Disclaimer: I haven't tried that.

Comment: @Jos That worked (`\011`)! Thank you. If you leave an answer, I'll accept it. Else, I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) there is no code for a horizontal tab, and `\t` displays the current time.

However, you can insert an arbitrary character into your prompt string by using `\xxx` where xxx is the octal ASCII code of the character. There is a [Tab character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key) for a horizontal tab, and its ASCII decimal code is 9. So you can get a horizontal tab in the prompt by inserting `\011` (being the octal value of decimal 9) into your sequence.