# How to shorten current working directory in bash prompt dynamicaly

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt

So I'm looking for a way to shorten the path in the prompt if it reaches a defined length, such as:

`user1@localhost:~/Pictures/awesome_trip/`

Would be fine, but if we cd into more sub-directories such as:

`user1@localhost:~/Pictures/awesome_trip/first_day/mikes_camera/funny_pics`

I would like the prompt to change to

`user1@localhost:/.../funny_pics`

I know how to change the prompt in the .bashrc

I was wondering if there is a way to make it dynamically such that I can get the current length of the working dir and check the length, and change the prompt. something along the lines of:

```
CUR_PROMPT=$(pwd); # get the working dir

CUR_PROMPT_LENGTH={#CUR_PROMPT}; # get the length

if[ $CUR_PROMPT_LENGTH -gt 20 ]; then 
  # if prompt is long, render shorter version
  PS1='\u@\h:...\w:\$';
else
  # else render long version
  PS1='\u@\h:\W:\$'
```

Hopefully there is way to do this,
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The bash shell already implements a `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` mechanism for that - see [How can I shorten my command line (bash) prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/a/459355/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver This is exactly what I was looking for. I can't believe i did not come across it while googling it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the code below. Just add it to your .bashrc file in your home folder. It will basically make your prompt resemble "user@computername [dir] $" so it might look like telegonicaxx@laptop [shared] $

```
export PS1="\u@\h [\W] \\$\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

You can generate your own prompt style and colors using the website linked below

http://bashrcgenerator.com/

Comment: Thank you @Roxana, this is really neat website, thank you for sharing it. Not exactly what I was looking for though