# Folder path in terminal too long

Tags: command-line

When i'm in a deep folder hierarchy the entire list of folders are seen before **$**

[image]

How can i make this short even though i'm in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an easy way to do this, but take a look at this question for more information on how to write a script to do this for you:

[trim the terminal command prompt working directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17723/trim-the-terminal-command-prompt-working-directory)

Best, 
Lev

Comment: I suggest to use the [2nd answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/29580/175814) though. The first is a bit inelegant and outdated.