# Change bash title to show truncated pwd

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I use tilda as my terminal on Ubunut 14.10. The trouble I have is that I want to have the tab bar, since the titles in it are actually useful for navigation, but having username@computer:~/some/folder is irritating. So I looked around, and yes, I can change bash's title so that it doesn't display the username and computer.

But that only partially solves the problem, because even if I only have the pwd as the title, it grows really fast. And I don't need the whole path, so I was wondering if there is a way to set the maximum size of the title. So that if I'm in

```
/home/username/Downloads/some_unzipped_folder/subfolder/
```

The title is displayed as

```
/home/usern...folder/subfolder/
```

depending on how much width I set, so that I get some useful information from the title, but not have my tab bar in tilda fill up quickly.

Comment: How do you change bash's title?

Comment: Did you try setting `PROMPT_DIRTRIM`? http://askubuntu.com/a/29580/158442

Comment: @choroba using this http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title.html

Comment: @muru Yeah, that works!

Comment: @muru Though it has the problem that I lose the initial folders in the path, and the path can still get long if the folder names are unwieldy.

Comment: @hoodakaushal if you want that, try the second solution in that answer. I think it retains the first ten characters as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bash variable string subsetting. For example

```
echo "${PWD:(-10)}"
```

to only show the last 10 characters. Change this value as you want.
So for the bash title, set the `PS1` variable (to do it permanent, put the line into `~/.bashrc`). For example:

```
PS1="[...]$(echo ${PWD:(-5)}) $ "
```

Use `sed` for more complex pattern changing (e.g. the middle part of the path).

Comment: In the similar question @muru is pointing at, there is a more complex example. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17723/trim-the-terminal-command-prompt-working-directory/29580#29580).