# How can I change the Terminal prompt to something simple?

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide current working directory in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16728/hide-current-working-directory-in-terminal)

When I open a terminal it shows something like `dave@daves:~$` or `dave@daves:~/Desktop$`. I don't want the `dave@daves` to show up. Can this be modified to show only the time or something simple like a DOS prompt?

Comment: What you want is what you want, but I find it incredibly useful to have the username@currentserver as part of the prompt. Quite often I'm remoted into a few different systems, and the prompt is an easy way to keep track of which terminal is logged into which system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could put `PS1='\w> '` in your `~/.bashrc`.

It will look like this:

```
~>
```

when you are in your home directory, and

```
/usr/bin>
```

when you are in `/usr/bin`.

There are four different time formats you can have:

- `\t` - 24-hour HH:MM:SS
- `\T` - 12-hour HH:MM:SS
- `\A` - 24-hour HH:MM (i.e. no seconds)
- `\@` - 12-hour HH:MM

so for example:

```
PS1='\A \w> '
```

would give you something like:

```
10:14 ~>
```

See [Controlling the Prompt](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt) for a list of all the different backslash sequences you can use.

If you can't find one you like, you can also add the output of any command to your prompt, e.g.

```
PS1='$(date +"%H:%M") $(echo $PWD)> '
```

would do basically the same as above, but using commands rather than backslash sequences.

Finally, note that the quotes and spaces are important.  The easiest way to get `PS1='\A \w> '` as your prompt is to run this:

```
echo "PS1='\A \w> '" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Excellent, Just what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have this as my Linux prompt.
C:\home\jj>

in my .bashrc I have these 2 variables...

```
DOS='C:${PWD//\//\\\}>'
PS1="\[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;31m\]$MKF\n\[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;39m\]$DOS\[\033[00m\]"
```

but then again,
I am sicker than most.