# Removing terminal username and path information?

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide current working directory in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16728/hide-current-working-directory-in-terminal)

In the terminal, you are present with the following:

```
<user>@<machine>:<path>$
```

How can I modify this so that it only displays the dollar sign, since the rest of that information is easily available.