# shorten file path in terminal

Tags: command-line, 13.04

I would like to shorten the file path that is currently active in the terminal to allow more space.  This is a shortened example but I sometimes have filepaths that I am working with that are 6 levels deep and it would be nice to hide that.

```
test@ubuntu:~$ cd code/helloworld
test@ubuntu:~/code/helloworld$
```

would like to just see somehting like

```
helloworld:
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably you are looking for something like this ?

[Hide current working directory in terminal][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16728/hide-current-working-directory-in-terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to your `.bashrc` or run at a prompt:

```
PS1='\W: '
```

For background information, run `man bash` and search for PROMPTING.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Ubuntu 19:10 and there is a file called `.bashrc` in my home directory. I can see it with the file-explorer by showing hidden files with `CTRL+H` and open it with my default text editor via double click *(my default user permissions are good - no `sudo` stuff needed in home)*.

There is a lot of configuration script and in between this:

```sh
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

based on [Pauls answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/302673/299951) I changed the lower-case `\w` to capital `\W`. It now looks like this…

```sh
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\W\$ '
fi
```

… and the terminal prefix is now `user@my-laptop:some_folder$`

---

*Sidenote: `[\033[01;32m\]` these things are color codes*

Hope this helps some GUI veterans :)