# What is the correct way to run a command after boot on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boot, command-line, 18.04, init

I need to run a simple batch of commands after the computer boots, something like

```
sudo thing
sudo thing1 -p
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out how.
I googled and googled and I kept finding the same thing: Place the commands into a /etc/rc.local or /etc/init.d/rc.local file. The problem is that none of those files exist on my system!
Furthermore, I have read that /etc/rc.local is deprecated anyway, so what the correct and simple way to do this?

I would like to know how to these two things:

- run a command after the computer boots
- run a command after specified user logs in, and run it as the given user

  (And make all that happen solely by editing stuff in the terminal, no GUI tools)

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1528/bashrc-or-bash-profile.  *You have five places you can add commands, you pick the best choice for your need...*  (See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/121413/understanding-bashrc-and-bash-profile *but there may be better too*)

Comment: To run commands as root I’d use root’s cron (`sudo crontab -e`) with the `@reboot` keyword as explained [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/816/507051), to run a command when a user logs in there the `~/.profile` approach as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/270050/507051).

Comment: Looks like admins do not know meaning of start-up and confusing it with user login. Could anyone please answer this? I do not see point in using crontab over enabling rc-local unit and creating rc.local.

Comment: @wick: mods on StackExchange sites, paradoxically, aren't required to know much about the topic of the question. They simply have mod powers, and sometimes make bad decisions because they don't understand the technical nature of the question.